# Controller changes not propagated to Directive

Tags: angularjs

Other SO questions seem to be about children talking to parents but this is the other way around. I'm sure I've missed something simple.

I'm trying to compenentise one of my existing sites that provides editing of gps tracks (as Json data). My custom element use two data sources - lapdata and selected - and these can change occasionally.

I had expected that using `'='` binding would update `$scope.selected` and thus `this.selectedPoints` during the digest cycle, but that's not what is happening.

**In other words, if `vm.selected[$index]` changes, I would like the `ng-class="{'selected': vm.selectedPoints[$index]}"` statements in the template to be updated.**

And if `vm.data.Lap[0].Track[0].Trackpoint.length` changes why does (which I assume would trigger `ng-repeat="lap in vm.data.Lap track by $index"` ) not rerun the `ng-repeat` within the Directive?

```
Points in first lap: {{vm.data.Lap[0].Track[0].Trackpoint.length}}        
div.data-table(ng-repeat="lap in vm.data.Lap track by $index")
            lap(
                count="{{$index}}", 
                lapdata="lap.Track[0].Trackpoint", 
                change="vm.checkChange(lapIdx, idx, shift)",
                selected="vm.selected[$index]")
```

This is the lap Directive. (count and change seem to work fine)

```
var LapDir = function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            lapdata: '=',
            selected: '=',
            count: '@',
            change: '&'
        },
        controller : function($scope) {
            this.lapdata = $scope.lapdata;
            $scope.selected = $scope.selected || {};
            this.selectedPoints = $scope.selected;

            this.select = (evt, idx) => {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                $scope.change({
                    lapIdx: $scope.count,
                    idx: idx,
                    shift: (evt.shiftKey)
                });
            };
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: 'editor/lap.tmpl.html'
    }
}
```

And then this is its template

```
tr(
    ng-repeat="tp in vm.lapdata track by $index", 
    class="trackpoint c{{$index}}",
    ng-class="{'selected': vm.selectedPoints[$index]}" 
    ng-click="vm.select($event, $index)")

    td {{tp.Time[0] | date: 'H:mm:ss'}}
    td
    td {{tp.DistanceMeters[0] | number : 1}} m
```

Comment: It's not really clear what this is meant to do; there isn't enough context here to try to create fake data and try to reproduce the behavior you are describing here.

Comment: I can say, however, that the use of `$index` here is suspect;  `$index` represents the count of a rendered item only; trying to link it to functional behavior can lead to all sorts of issues, since this value is never guaranteed.

Comment: I added a little more code

Comment: most definitely, the `$index` of the outer repeat and the `$index` in the template wouldn't be the same; there is definitely something wrong with this logic.

Comment: I don't want them to be the same, the outer one is about laps and the inner is a trackpoint.

Comment: right, but you are trying in the inner template to ask if the `lap` at the `trackpoint` `$index` are selected.  That's not going to give you the result you expect.

Comment: again, I would really encourage against the use of `$index` when trying to perform this sort of logic.

Comment: $scope.selected = $scope.selected || {}; << this line may completely destroy your bindings. this.selectedPoints = $scope.selected; << this line is what for? you need two same objects?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov No I am trying to get the data passed in (which is attached to `scope` by tradition) attached to `this` as I use `ControllerAs` syntax

Comment: its up to u. BUt u definitely should remove this: $scope.selected = $scope.selected || {};

Comment: instead of re-assigning your variables, use `bindToController: true` if you want your isolate scope variables in the controller.

Comment: Thanks @Claies - I had just discovered by experimentation that it was the assignment to `this.` that was blocking things. It works if I remove references to `this` but then I know I am relying on `$scope` in the background and that's old practise. Let me read up about `bindToController`

Comment: it's probably not specifically the use of `this`, it is more likely that conditional.  if you assign `$scope.selected = {}`, it is no longer two way bound.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Still struggling to rewire `$scope.change`, i.e. my `'&'` bound function